# How to detach an instance from a Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I would like to delete/detach an instance from an ELB (but not delete the instance itself).

The API seems to require specific port number/s for [DeleteLoadBalancerListeners](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/us-delete-listener.html).

How do I just remove it entirely from the LB (all ports)? (Just like the GUI action "Remove from Load Balancer" in AWS)

I'm using the [Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_ElasticLoadBalancing_Model_DeleteLoadBalancerListenersRequest.htm).

Comment: Actually, DeleteLoadBalancerListeners doesn't seem to be what I want at all ... it doesn't accept the ID of the instance to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To de-register your back-end instance from your load balancer

Call DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer with the following parameters:

```
Instances = i-4e05f721
LoadBalancerName = MyLoadBalancer
```

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_DeReg_Reg_Instances.html

Your link to the Java SDK goes to the C# SDK, but in the same API doc you can find

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_ElasticLoadBalancing_Model_DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancerRequest.htm

Thats what you're looking for, right?

Comment: I just found this out 37 seconds after your post, and posted my own answer ... then saw yours :) Accepted & deleted mine.